# How to create ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC)?

Tags: initramfs, cpio, mkinitcpio

I have a file in `/boot/initramfs.gz`

extract it using `tar -xzvf initramfs.gz -C ./` I got a file `initramfs`.

`└──╼ $ file initramfs
initramfs: ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC)`

It can be open using `ark`. But I want to change some files in this file `initramfs`.

[image]

I extracted it using `ark` and got a folder `initramfs`. Now I want to save it as before.

[image]

How do I create an ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC) like the original?

Comment: You use `cpio` from the command line.  However you probably _don't_ want to change initramfs files this way; next time you do an update which installs a patched kernel then the new initramfs generated for the new kernel won't have your changes in it.  You should follow your OS distribution processes for adding files and stuff into it, so they are persisted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You [can do this with GNU cpio](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt):

```
$ find . | cpio -o -H newc > /tmp/file
40 blocks
$ file /tmp/file
/tmp/file: ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC)
```

Comment: simple and best!

Comment: `cpio -o -H newc` cpio: Invalid header "newc" specified
USAGE:
        cpio -i[bcdfkmrstuv@BSV6] [-C size] [-E file] [-H hdr] [-I file [-M msg]] [-R id] [patterns]
        cpio -o[acv@ABLV] [-C size] [-H hdr] [-O file [-M msg]]
        cpio -p[adlmuv@LV] [-R id] directory
Better use `cpio -o -c`.